# How can I modify my Akka streams Prime sieve to exclude modulo checks for known primes?

Tags: algorithm, akka, sieve-of-eratosthenes, akka-stream

I wrote a sieve using `akka` streams to find prime members of an arbitrary source of `Int`:

```
object Sieve extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(system))
  implicit val ctx = implicitly[ExecutionContext](system.dispatcher)

  val NaturalNumbers = Source.fromIterator(() => Iterator.from(2))

  val IsPrimeByEurithmethes: Flow[Int, Int, _] = Flow[Int].filter {
    case n: Int =>
      (2 to Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)).toInt).par.forall(n % _ != 0)
  }

  NaturalNumbers.via(IsPrimeByEurithmethes).throttle(100000, 1 second, 100000, ThrottleMode.Shaping).to(Sink.foreach(println)).run()
}
```

Ok, so this appears to work decently well. However, there are at least a few potential areas of concern:

1. The modulo checks are run using `par.forall`, ie they are totally hidden within the `Flow` that `filter`s, but I can see how it would be useful to have a `Map` from the `candidate n` to another `Map` of each `n % _`. Maybe.
2. I am checking way too many of the candidates needlessly - both in terms of checking `n` that I will already know are NOT prime based on previous results, and by checking `n % _` that are redundant. In fact, even if I think the `n` is prime, it suffices to check only the known primes up until that point.

The second point is my more immediate concern.

I think I can prove rather easily that there is a more efficient way - by filtering out the `source` given each NEW prime.

So then....

```
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11... => (after finding p=2)

2, 3,    5,    7,    9,   , 11... => (after finding p=3)

2, 3,    5,    7,         , 11... => ...
```

Now after finding a `p` and filtering the source, we need to know whether the next candidate is a `p`. Well, we can say for sure it is prime if the largest known prime is greater than its root, which will Always happen I believe, so it suffices to just pick the next element...

```
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11... => (after finding p=2) PICK n(2) = 3

2, 3,    5,    7,    9,   , 11... => (after finding p=3) PICK n(3) = 5

2, 3,    5,    7,         , 11... => (after finding p=5) PICK n(5) = 7
```

This seems to me like a rewriting of the originally-provided sieve to do far fewer checks at the cost of introducing a strict sequential dependency.

Another idea - I could remove the constraint by working things out in terms of symbols, like the minimum set of modulo checks that necessitate primality, etc.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? IF not, how can I go about messing with my source in this manner?

Answer (score 2):

I just started fiddling around with akka streams recently so there might be better solutions than this (especially since the code feels kind of clumsy to me) - but your second point seemed to be just the right challenge for me to try out building a feedback loop within akka streams.

Find my full solution here: https://gist.github.com/MartinHH/de62b3b081ccfee4ae7320298edd81ee

The main idea was to accumulate the primes that are already found and merge them with the stream of incoming natural numbers so the primes-check could be done based on the results up to N like this:

```
def isPrime(n: Int, primesSoFar: SortedSet[Int]): Boolean =
  !primesSoFar.exists(n % _ == 0) &&
    !(primesSoFar.lastOption.getOrElse(2) to Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n)).toInt).par.exists(n % _ == 0)
```

Comment: So... this works :) but it is not using the substreaming that I am kind of looking to use and you mentioned as well