# Akka streaming - accessible examples of manual flow control, especially cycles or recursion

Tags: akka, akka-stream

See my other question: [How can I modify my Akka streams Prime sieve to exclude modulo checks for known primes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36381603/how-can-i-modify-my-akka-streams-prime-sieve-to-exclude-modulo-checks-for-known) for an example of the kind of problem I have in mind.

In studying Akka streams thus far I have been surprised by how little discussion is devoted towards the specifics on flow control within the pipe, especially in terms of 1) timing/waiting, 2) futures within `GraphDSL.create`, and 3) **making use of existing, already processed values**.

Certain flows, for instance, have a "costly calculation step" that is limiting. For primes, that's checking for all `p` to `Math.floor(Math.sqrt(whatvever))`. Well, it would be best if I only checked the known `p` modulo, but I end up checking ALL numbers less than the root because I don't know how to use the data I am gathering. With a cheap lookup step in plcae, I could save a lot of time.

Similarly, maybe I want to work on implementing a flow at such a low level it might a well be item by item. I was expecting to find examples where I could do something like... `Item(n = 3) => Add three seconds of runtime, Item(n = -1) => Hold for 1 second... whateer. Is there a way to work at that level and remain within akka?